# Capital Gain report with currency conversion of purchase cost

Tags: australia, gnucash

I have setup gnucash in my windows laptop. It does what I want and it does flawlessly. I have one question though. My default currency is AUD. I have investments in shares in indian currency. Using lots, it calculates capital gains correctly. beautiful. But one of the requirements by ATO when reporting capital gains earned in currency other than AUD, is to convert the purchase value in to AUD, at the time the share was bought and also convert to aud the sale value at date of sale and calculate the capital gain in AUD by calculating the diff between the aud value of sale and aud value of purchase. I have even setup the Finance-Quote module. I tried to print the report in common curency, but it still shows capital gain as one transaction and converts to aud based on the exchange rate on date of sale.
Does anyone know how to do this?

I tried activating trading accounts. But still I could not get what i want. 
For example. for the following transactions

1. purchase stock ABC on 14/04/2004  for INR 40000.00 AUD 1000.00 (for example ex rate AUD-INR = 40 on 14/4/2004 or month end avg rate)
2. sell stock ABC on 30/6/2019 for INR  60,000.00 AUD 1200.00 (assuming ex rate as 50.00 on 30/62019 before )

When I run the capital gains report for FY 2018-19 I want the capital gains to be calculated in both currencies

1. INR 60,000.00 - 40,000.00 = 20,000.00
2. AUD 1200.00 - 1000.00 = 200.00  (not as 20,000.00 / 50 = 400)

Ravi